# How to disassemble free hub shell?

Tags: wheel-building, freehub

I need to replace the free hub shell that is on my wheel with one that will work with an 11-speed Dura-Ace cassette.  The current one is for Campagnolo.

I don't want to take the whole wheel apart, I only want to remove the part that the cassette goes into.

[image]
I took the bolt out.

[image]
And I took the bearings out.

[image]
Now what?

Comment: What's the make/model of your wheels / hub?

Comment: That's enough on some hubs but perhaps there's a nut on the other side that needs removing too.

Comment: If it doesn't just pull off, there might be a large hex socket in the axle bore that needs undoing (probably 8mm or 10mm).

Comment: I'm guessing you're sure theres a replacement body thats compatible with Shimano for this hub, but just as a side note, you can interchange Shimano/SRAM/Campagnolo rear wheels for 11 speed in the other manufacturer's drivetrains and have something working: http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/09/bikes-and-tech/drivetrain-compatibility-hidden-in-plain-sight_303199

Comment: @alex Here's a link to the specs of te wheel.. http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=272020570847&category=177830&pm=1&ds=0&t=1466056057224

Comment: I do not know where to get the appropriate free hub body I need but was just told by the person who sold me the wheels that it needs to be 24h.

Comment: @davidcondrey 24h refers to the number of spoke holes in the hub shell, which has nothing to do with the freehub body.  If you wanted to replace the entire hub, you'd have to rebuild the wheel.  This is certainly an option, but probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Hoping to not have to replace the whole thing.  So I'm just hoping once I get the current body off I can figure out from there what body I need to get that will fit.

Answer (score 1):

On the hub side of the freehub, there should be a Allen headed bolt that you need to unscrew.  Some are 8mm, others are 10mm and some are 11mm.  11mm is a hard to find Allen wrench, so hopefully it's 8 or 10mm.
Put the Allen wrench into the center the freehub and unscrew in the normal direction (CCW).

Comment: @Suspended User Thanks for fixing my mistake.  I use the two terms synonymously, but they are technically different.

Comment: I understood and assume most would as well, but wanted to ensure it's correctness for search.  Thanks!

Comment: Some unscrew on the opposite side to the freehub, in which case you need an extra long wrench.